# How to convert date entries in OHLC data frame in Python to strings in order to use date time module to inspect dates

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

```
In[118]: Date.iloc[0].to_string()
Out[118]: 'Date    1997-09-09'
```

How do I eliminate "Date" from string in order to use date time module

Answer (score 2):

Pass [`index=False`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_string.html):

```
Date.iloc[0].to_string(index=False)
```

Comment: IMO: the df is named 'Date', and Column named 'Date'.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Date.iloc[0, 0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

consider `tidx`

```
tidx = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=2)
```

both print the same thing.

```
print(tidx.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
print(tidx.to_series().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').values)

['2000-01-01' '2000-01-02']
['2000-01-01' '2000-01-02']
```

Comment: I think `Date` is a DataFrame (with a single column) because otherwise to_string would raise an error.  You may need to add a `[0]` index at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.iloc[0].to_string()[-10:]
Out[129]: '1997-09-09'
```